# How to use user input in a conditional (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, user-input

I've made a simple volume of a sphere calculator w/ user input:

```
clc

%Ask For Radius
radius = input ('What is the radius of your sphere?');

%Calculate Volume Using Radius
vlm = (4/3) * pi * radius^3 ;

%Return Radius
fprintf('The volume of your sphere is %4.2f inches cubed\n', vlm)
```

But I decided I wanted to go one step further and give the user the option to ask another and another until they don't want to do anymore. However I'm stuck as I can't figure out how to take this user input:

```
again = input ('Do You Want To Find The Volume Of A Sphere?','s')
```

And apply it to a conditional such as and if else statement. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
if again = yes
    %Ask For Radius
    %Insert VolumeOfSphere.m
else 
    fprintf('Ok, Just run Me Again If You Want To Calculate Another Sphere')
    %Add An End program Command
end
```

Any help or tips in the right direction is very much appreciated in advance.

Comment: [`while`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excaza is right, a while loop sounds like what you need. A basic implementation of this might be:

```
clc; clear;

while true
    %Ask For Radius
    radius = input ('What is the radius of your sphere?  ');

    %Calculate Volume Using Radius
    vlm = (4/3) * pi * radius^3 ;

    %Return Radius
    fprintf('The volume of your sphere is %4.2f inches cubed\n', vlm)

    % Ask if they want to run again
    run_again = input('\nWould you like to run again? Y or N:  ', 's');

    % Deal with their answer
    if     strcmpi(run_again, 'Y')
        % do nothing, let the loop keep running
    elseif strcmpi(run_again, 'N')
        break % this will break out of the while loop and end the program
    else
        % assume they meant Y, and send them back to the start
    end

end
```